# How to write test class for selectoption

Tags: unit-test, controller-extension

I want to write test class for for below controller

**Controller**

```
public class OrederSendEmail {

public List<SelectOption> getEmailFrom() 
{

List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();

List<OrgwideEmailAddress> org = [Select id,Address from OrgwideEmailAddress];

for(OrgwideEmailAddress name : org)

{

     objNames.add(new SelectOption(name.Id,name.Address));

}

return objNames;


}

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectNames() {
        List<SelectOption> objNames= new List<SelectOption>();
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Account Receivables','Account Receivables'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Asset','Asset'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Bus Details','Bus Details'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Campaign','Campaign'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Account Receivables','Account Receivables'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Case','Case'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Contract','Contract'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Course','Course'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Product','Product'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Asset','Asset'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('CustomOrder','CustomOrder'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Contact','Contact'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Practice','Practice'));
        objNames.add(new SelectOption('Order','Order'));

        return objNames;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getMyPersonalTemplateOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (EmailTemplate t : [select Id,Name,Subject,body from EmailTemplate]) 
         {
            Maptemp.put(t.Id,t);
            options.add(new SelectOption(t.Id,t.Name));
        }
        return options;

    }
}
```

can any one help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code.

You need to instantiate the class and call the methods of that class:

```
@isTest                    
public class OrederSendEmailTest {

    public static testMethod void testOrederSendEmail() {
        OrederSendEmail controller = new OrederSendEmail();
        Test.startTest();
        List<SelectOption> emailFromOptns = controller.getEmailFrom();
        List<SelectOption> objectNamesOptns = controller.getObjectNames();
        List<SelectOption> myPersonalTemplateOptns = controller.getMyPersonalTemplateOptions();
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertNotEquals(objectNamesOptns ,null);
    }   
}
```

See [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) as a reference for writing Test Classes